# Why is 1 yr. return of FXAIX is being calculated as 10.41% as on today's date?

Tags: mutual-funds

According to [Fidelity website](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/315911750), $10,000 invested in `FXAIX` on 9/5/2018 becomes $10,515 on 9/5/2019. However, in **Quarter-End Average Annual Total Returns** section, it says the 1 yr. return from the fund is 10.41%. However, I calculate it as `(10515-10000)/10000% = 5.15%`. Why is there this discrepancy? How are they calculating the figure they are advertising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word is "Quarter-End". The 10.41% one-year return is as of 6/30/2019.

It refers to the period whose end coincides with the end of the most recently completed quarter (here, Q2, which is 4/1-6/30). Thus, the 10.41% one-year return is calculated from 6/30/2018 to 6/30/2019